# Route through site-to-site VPN not working

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, pptp, rras

I'm trying to set up a site-to-site VPN using RRAS on two 2K8r2 servers since yesterday. The connection is working at this point, but I can't get it to send traffic from one site to the other one.

**Set up:** the set up is the same on both sites: the server is connected to a router that's connected to a modem. The routers act like a DHCP-server and assign IP addresses from the range subnet.21-subnet-.100. Both servers use a static IP address, subnet.11, and are set up as DMZ.

**Configuration:** the servers are configured using the wizard to set up a site-to-site connection. This works with a demand-dial interface and a PPTP VPN connection. As mentioned, the VPN connection work properly.

**Problem:** I can't get the servers to send the traffic for the other site, to be sent through the VPN connection. I added a static route on both server ([home](http://bit.ly/dVp0aI), [office 1](http://bit.ly/hPelJ1)) and I can see the result in the IP routing table ([home](http://bit.ly/heQvUV), [office 1](http://bit.ly/hvghUP)). I did this because the route didn't show up automatically. My guess is that this last step isn't right, for example because the routing table states "non demand-dial", which seems not correct.

**Home:**

- Subnet: 10.0.1.0/24
- Router: 10.0.1.1
- Server: 10.0.1.11 (DMZ)
- DHCP: 10.0.1.21-10.0.1.100
- RRAS DHCP: 10.0.1.101-10.0.1.150

**Office 1:**

- Subnet: 10.0.2.0/24
- Router: 10.0.2.1
- Server: 10.0.2.11 (DMZ)
- DHCP: 10.0.2.21-10.0.2.100
- RRAS DHCP: 10.0.2.101-10.0.2.150

I hope someone has an idea to get this route working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by server? Is this the server that works as the vpn server?

Because when you still have a separate internet connection with a router at .1 than that is used as the gateway for ip's not in de same range.

Try setting your default gateway on your client computers to .11

Comment: The server is the computer that runs 2K8r2. It's a simple setup with just one server on each site. So yes, that servers works as the VPN server.

I tried to connect to the other site from the server itself, so the clients don't have a role at this moment. I just set the default gateway to .11 on the server on the outside site, but I lost my RDP connection and can't get connected now ;-)